# Ошибка: Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для беззнакового байта

Tags: c#

Есть функция

```
private ushort GetCRC16(byte[] block,  // Заданная последовательность байт
                   ushort length,   // Длина последовательности
                   ushort bases,    // Начальное значение
                   ushort polynom   // Полином преобразования 
          )
{
    ushort reg;
    int i, j;

    // Загрузить в двухбайтовый регистр (назовем его CRC-регистром) начальное 
    значение CRC
    reg = bases;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        // Сложить по модулю 2 младший байт CRC-регистра с i байтом      
        последовательности и поместить результат в CRC-регистр
        reg ^= block[i];
        // 8 раз сдвинуть вправо CRC-регистр на флаг переноса (бит старшего байта                  заместить нулем)
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            // Если флаг переноса = 1 
            if ((reg & 0x0001) != 0)
                // Cложить по модулю 2 содержимое CRC-регистра с константой crc16_POLYNOM
                reg = Convert.ToUInt16((reg >> 0x0001) ^ polynom);
            else
                reg >>= 0x0001;
    }
    return reg;
}
```

Я её вызываю:

```
ushort CRC16 = GetCRC16(OutPacket, 2, 0, 0x1021);
```

Ошибок нет.
После этого:

```
byte CRC16Low = Convert.ToByte(CRC16);
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для
>   беззнакового байта

Пробовал отладить, но ошибка возникает тут же при вызове функции, не могу в неё зайти.

Answer (score 3):

Размер типа byte в C# фиксирован и составляет (сюрприз-сюрприз) один байт. То есть в него можно писать значения от 0 до 255. Тогда как ushort - 2 байта с диапазоном от 0 до 65535.   В результате вызова вашей функции вы получаете переменную типа ushort со значением 2182 и пытаетесь ее сконвертировать в тип меньшей размерности, отчего получаете исключение. И еще - небольшое дополнение - а зачем вы передаете в функцию размер массива? Вы можете получить его из самого массива:

```
for (i = 0; i < block.Length; i++)
```

Comment: ок, спасибо. length - это видимо не размер массива, а длина данных до байтов контрольной суммы (после неё есть байты - признаки конца). Функцию писал не я. Мне нужно двухбайтное число разделить на 2 байта. тогда как мне быть?

Comment: @olegall:

    byte high = value >> 8;
    byte low  = (byte)value;

или лучше [`BitConverter.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66.aspx).